# Which concept to use for Responsive design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend, bootstrap-5

I recently studied responsive images article from MDN in which they had used tags like `<srcset>` and `<picture>` for art direction and resolution switching problem.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Previously, I had an exposure to media queries and bootstrap for responsive design.

So, currently confused between these things when to use which one....please help on this.

Comment: Responsive design means your website will adapt to look good on any device. You would use both.

Comment: `min-width` media queries can be used to add in layout complexity for wider screens whereas a picture element is used with srcsets and a fallback img element to provide the browser with options for downloading images (depending on what formats is supports and what resolution is required).